# Error programmatically rendering an invoice PDF

Tags: magento2, invoice

The error:

> Invalid template file: 'Magento_Payment::info/pdf/default.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Payment' block's name: 'info\instructions_0'

The class:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\PDF\Response\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request;
use Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\RendererInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice as InvoicePdf;

class PdfRenderer implements RendererInterface
{
    private $request;
    private $invoiceRepository;
    private $invoicePdf;

    /**
     * Pdf constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface $invoiceRepository
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice $invoicePdf
     */
    public function __construct(
        Request $request,
        InvoiceRepositoryInterface $invoiceRepository,
        InvoicePdf $invoicePdf
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->invoiceRepository = $invoiceRepository;
        $this->invoicePdf = $invoicePdf;
    }

    /**
     * Render content in a certain format.
     *
     * @param object|array|int|string|bool|float|null $data
     * @return string
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception
     */
    public function render($data)
    {
        if (!strstr($this->request->getPathInfo(), '/V1/invoices')) {
            throw new Exception(__('PDF rendering is not supported for this URI'));
        }

        if (isset($data['entity_id'])) {
            $invoice = $this->invoiceRepository->get($data['entity_id']);

            try {
                $pdf = $this->invoicePdf->getPdf([$invoice]);

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                header("Content-type: application/json");
                exit(json_encode([
                    "operationPerformed" => false,
                    "message" => $e->getMessage()
                ]));
            }

            return $pdf->render();
        } 

        throw new Exception(__('Invoice not found'));
    }

    /**
     * Get MIME type generated by renderer.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMimeType()
    {
        return 'application/pdf';
    }
}
```

The error happens when doing `$this->invoicePdf->getPdf([$invoice])`.

**UPDATE:**

Solved as suggested from the comments, by emulating the area code 'adminhtml'.
For reference, this is my code:

```
$this->appState->emulateAreaCode("adminhtml",
    function($invoice, &$pdf) {    
        $pdf = $this->invoicePdf->getPdf([$invoice]);
    },
    [$invoice, &$pdf]
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the area code you are running your code with is not the admin. Depending on the payment method used, the fault occurs when the template for the Info block payment is called.

for instance, an order using check / money payment method will have the error at the function `\Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Info\Checkmo::toPdf`

I attach a screenshot showing you the payment module templates admin area comes with[image] a pdf folder and frontend does not.

Comment: Oh I understand. So do you think is not possible to render the pdf via REST API (because as you said, that's not an adminhtml code area)? What could be the workaround?

Comment: you can use the way magento has to emulate. please see \Magento\Framework\App\State::emulateAreaCode

Comment: It worked by simulating the area code, thank you so much! I'm updating the question with the correct code.